# Count rows in a foreign dataframe

Tags: r, join, tidyr

Consider the following problem: I have two dataframes `cases` and `events`. For every `case` there can be several `events` (1:n). events$caseId (foreign key) refers to cases$id (primary key):

```
cases       events
------      ------
id          id
date        caseId
var1        date
var2        var1
...         var2
            ...
```

Now, I'd like to create a new column in `cases` giving the number of events for every case (i.e. where events$caseId equals cases$id)

```
# Sample data            
cases<-data.frame(id=1:5, date=c("2017-01-02","2016-02-03","2015-02-12","2016-01-03","2016-08-09"), var1=sample(c("A", "B"), 5, replace=T))
events<-data.frame(id=1:10, date=c("2017-01-01","2016-12-12","2016-07-04","2017-04-03","2015-02-13","2015-01-01","2013-05-07","2015-12-25","2016-05-04","2016-10-11"), caseId=c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,4,5,5))

# Calculate the number of events for every caseId
library(tidyverse)
events %>%  
  count(caseId) %>%
  right_join(cases, by = c("caseId" = "id"))
```

The problem I have is that I want to count **only those events that happened after the date specified in the `case`-dataframe  (i.e. events$date > cases$date)**.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you please show your expected output for the sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a non-equi join with the data.table package (the `date`-columns need to be converted to date-format first, see below under **Data**-heading):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(cases)
setDT(events)

cases[events, on = .(id = caseId, date < date), events := .N, by = .EACHI][]
```

The result:

```
   id       date var1 events
1:  1 2017-01-02    B      1
2:  2 2016-02-03    A     NA
3:  3 2015-02-12    A      1
4:  4 2016-01-03    B     NA
5:  5 2016-08-09    B      1
```

A variant of this:

```
cases[, events := events[cases, on = .(caseId = id, date > date), .N, by = .EACHI]$N][]
```

The result of that:

```
   id       date var1 events
1:  1 2017-01-02    A      1
2:  2 2016-02-03    A      0
3:  3 2015-02-12    A      1
4:  4 2016-01-03    A      0
5:  5 2016-08-09    A      1
```

### Data:

```
cases <- data.frame(id=1:5, date=c("2017-01-02","2016-02-03","2015-02-12","2016-01-03","2016-08-09"),
                    var1=sample(c("A", "B"), 5, replace=T))
events <- data.frame(id=1:10,
                     date=c("2017-01-01","2016-12-12","2016-07-04","2017-04-03","2015-02-13","2015-01-01","2013-05-07","2015-12-25","2016-05-04","2016-10-11"),
                     caseId=c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,4,5,5))
cases$date <- as.Date(cases$date)
events$date <- as.Date(events$date)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at your solution trying it with the actual data. I am not familiar with the data.table-syntax at all though.

Comment: @ h3rm4n: What if I wanted to add an additional condition like counting only those events where caseId=id, date > date plus **events$var1=="A"**? I was trying it like this, but it didn't work:

cases[, events := events[cases, on = .(caseId = id, date > date, **varv1=='A'**), .N, by = .EACHI]$N][]